# Testing specific text on page render a code smell?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, testing, rendering

Occasionally, I'll find tests written by others that relies on specific text to be on a page (ie. a success message, an empty warning, etc.)

I find these distasteful, and usually will replace them with either a test for a specific selector (ie. `#success-message` or `.error`) or an I18n value (ie. `I18n.t('foobar.success')` or `I18n.t('form.error.missing_error')`)

The latter seems more future proof, since if the copy changes then my tests won't fail. However, some have argued that if you accidentally change the message, then it won't be caught as a failure.

Is there a standard practice when utilizing these sorts of things that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

I do both in my tests: check selectors and check copy.  Its good if tests fail due to copy changes.  Its a bit more maintenance but the people who change copy should also be running tests or you should have a continuous integration setup to notify immediately if tests fail.

It gets a bit more complicated if you start running a/b or multivariant tests but it isn't insurmountable...Like I said, just more maintenance.

IMO, the tradeoff of maintenance vs confidence in code coverage is well worth it.